# How to find where docker-install.exe file is?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to uninstall docker toolbox following the instructions in here:

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

where it says:

Note: This process does not remove the docker-install.exe file. You must delete that file yourself.

But I cannot find that file anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: This is the original installer you downloaded

Comment: Thanks, now it is called DockerToolbox.exe. No wonder why i couldn't find it.

Comment: Answer the question if you want and we can close it. The instructions at https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/ are old and do not apply any longer. Shame on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the original installer you downloaded. It is currently called `DockerToolbox.exe`, the instructions are not up to date.